VS2022: An Error Occurred While Finding the Resource Dictionary
I have read through all the similar questions to see if one of the solutions works for me, and so far none have worked for me. I am attempting to build a window project in C# WPF .NET, and I really want to start building a style system so that my next few projects will have the same look without me having to do too much modification to the styles I create. But I'm getting stuck after just creating a style for just one element (buttons).
Here is my Solution Explorer:

And this is how I'm including the Resource Dictionary:
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="AddinCollectionViewSource" CollectionViewType="ListCollectionView"/>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="RevitStyles">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/RevitAddinManager;component/Assets/RevitStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

I have tried a few other methods, including:
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="RevitStyles" Source="pack://application:,,,/RevitAddinManager;component/Assets/RevitStyles.xaml"/>

Source="/Assets/RevitStyles.xaml"

Source=/RevitAddinManager/Assets/RevitStyles.xaml"

And I'm sure there's a few other things I've tried that didn't work. I've also tried starting a brand new project to no avail, and excluding/including the problem file from/to the solution.
So my question is what could I be doing wrong? Could it be an issue with how I've written the ResourceDictionary? Or is there something else I'm missing that anyone can think of?
For reference, here is what I have in my dictionary so far:
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style x:Key="RevitButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FFA0A0A0"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFE5F1FB"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF0078D6"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Focused.Background" Color="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource Button.Static.Background}}"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Focused.Border" Color="{Binding Color, Source={DynamicResource Button.MouseOver.Border}}"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFCCE4F7"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF005499"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFC9C9C9"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFA0A0A0"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="DimGray"/>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Forground}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border x:Name="Border"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                        <ContentPresenter Name="Content" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Focused.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Focused.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Content" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>

And the error I'm getting: An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "<whatever path I've tried to provide>".

The solution Tarazed posted didn't work for me initially, but it looks like I managed to rename the file incorrectly (I did not name it on creation through Visual Studio's file creator), and that was preventing the solution from finding the file from the correctly typed out Source. I had previous tried recreating the file to no avail and it is likely what Tarazed posted was the other half of the answer I needed at the time to get it working. After implementing his changes and then recreating the file with the desired name, it works!

Looks like you have a couple of problems.  So first off, Window.Resources is a property that must be assigned a ResourceDictionary.  You are adding a CollectionViewSource outside the ResourceDictionary, which is invalid.  The other problem is you are using the assembly reference Pack URI.  Since your resource is in the same executing assembly as your XAML, you want to use that Pack URI notation (without the component).  More about Pack URIs here.
<Window.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="AddinCollectionViewSource" CollectionViewType="ListCollectionView"/>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Assets/RevitStyles.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resource>


That's odd, because the CollectionViewSource was working fine outside of the ResourceDictionary. I actually had that before I started trying to develop a resourcedictionary at all and it was just an item contained within Window.Resources. I've fixed that to be more proper, anyway. But the ResourceDictionary is still giving me the same error. I wasn't sure if I had tried this method already or not because I've bounced around so many forums and posts here, but I do remember reviewing the page you linked.

Actually, it looks like the issue may no longer be with the path I've provided. I used the Right Click menu > Peek Definition on the Source value, and it took me to the correct file. I tried mucking with the spelling to redirect it to a non-existent file and it didn't work, so it seems as though VS is aware of the pathing, at least.
